# Color fragment based on angle to center of screen GLSL

Tags: opengl, glsl

As an exercise in learning fragment shaders / vector math I am trying to write a post processing shader that colors every point P on the screen based upon the angle (in radians) of the vector PC, between P and the Center of the screen C.

For simplicity sake I will be doing this in grayscale, but a good illustration of the effect I am going for can be seen here, with hue changing as the angle changes, and the hue forming a cycle.

http://demosthenes.info/assets/images/hsl-color-wheel-trans.png

I've searched around, looking for information on finding the angles between vectors, and from those examples I've gotten to here:

```
#version 110

uniform sampler2D tex0; //Color info

void main()
{
    vec2 ScreenCenter = vec2(0.5 , 0.5);
    vec2 texCoord = gl_TexCoord[0].st;
    vec2 deltaTexCoord = ( texCoord - ScreenCenter.xy);    
    float angle = dot(deltaTexCoord , vec2(0,-1));

    //I've made attempts here to mess with acos as well as angle=pow(angle, somefloat) and
    //have not gotten desired results

    gl_FragColor = vec4( angle , angle, angle, 1.0 );
}
```

However this code produces linear gradients rather than the effect I want.

Comment: Despite attempts to simplify it as such, hue is not a number. Hue is a normalized 3D vector. Saturation and values are numbers, i.e. angle from grey, and distance from the origin, respectively.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the built-in GLSL function `atan()` with two arguments:

```
float angle = atan(deltaTexCoord.y, deltaTexCoord.x);
```

This corresponds to the [atan2 function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) that you're probably familiar with from C/C++. Compared to using `acos()`, the main advantage is that this gives you the full range of angles [-pi, pi], while the angles produced by `acos()` are only in the range [0, pi], and are therefore incorrect for the bottom half of the circle. With `atan(y, x)`, there is also no need to normalize the input values.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. The inner product (also called scalar or dot product) of two vectors is the *cosine* of the angles between the vectors times the product of the length of the vectors. So to get back to the angle you have map the dot product through the inverse of the cosine and normalize the vectors first (0,1) is already unit length so.

```
float angle = acos( dot(normalize(deltaTexCoord), vec2(0, -1)) );
```

Note that the angle is reported in units of radians, which go from 0 to 2pi.